# TimePicker and DateTime object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to implement a check in  my app that user must select time greater than current time along with i am taking their difference. I am taking time from  user through a time picker and comparing with a datetime object.
I am facing a problem doing this.

```
        DateTime  obj = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
        DateTime obj2 = Convert.ToDateTime(tp.Time);
        //Here tp.time is the time from timepicker.
        //But the exception isthrown that it cannot convert timespan to datetime. 

        TimeSpan ts = obj - obj2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Time from the TimePicker control is a TimeSpan.

To achieve what you are trying to do you can do the following:

```
DateTime  obj = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
DateTime obj2 = DateTime.Today.Add(tp.Time);

TimeSpan ts = obj - obj2;
```

Comment: no it doesnot work it says : cannot implicitly convert type timespan to date time object on line 3

Comment: @Kam I just had a little type on tp.Time. The rest is working fine. If this doesn't work tell me two things: What type is exactly the `tp` object and where are you using the `ts` object after this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var t1 = tp.Time;
var t2 = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan ts = t2 - t1;
```